# Cash Book Report

Tags: php

I use this code for generating Daily Cash Book, it generates single report between starting and ending date but I want to generate
or fetch data date wise, or 1st May report generate separately then 2nd May and so on.

```
<?php
include'connect.php';
$Receipts = mysql_query("SELECT vou_date, vou_no, acc_code, acc_name, narration,  ROUND(SUM(receipts),2) AS receipts FROM cash_book WHERE vou_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND  '2013-05-29' AND receipts > 0 AND vou_no LIKE 'CR' GROUP BY acc_code");
while($CBResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($Receipts)){
echo '
    <table border="0" width="900" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td scope="col" width="100" align="center">'.$CBResult['vou_no'].'</td>
        <td scope="col" width="100" align="center">'.$CBResult['acc_code'].'</td>
        <td scope="col" width="200" align="left">'.$CBResult['acc_name'].'</td>
        <td scope="col" width="400" align="left">'.$CBResult['narration'].'</td>
        <td scope="col" width="100" align="right">'.$CBResult['receipts'].'</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
'; 
}
$Payments = mysql_query("SELECT vou_date, vou_no, acc_code, acc_name, narration,  ROUND(SUM(payments),2) AS payments FROM cash_book WHERE vou_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-29' AND payments > 0 AND vou_no LIKE 'CP' GROUP BY acc_code");
while($CBResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($Payments)){
echo '
    <table border="0" width="900" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td scope="col" width="100" align="center">'.$CBResult['vou_no'].'</td>
        <td scope="col" width="100" align="center">'.$CBResult['acc_code'].'</td>
        <td scope="col" width="200" align="left">'.$CBResult['acc_name'].'</td>
        <td scope="col" width="400" align="left">'.$CBResult['narration'].'</td>
        <td scope="col" width="100" align="right">'.$CBResult['receipts'].'</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
';
}
?>
```

Comment: whats the problem, whats the question

Comment: @Petros, It generates a single report with all entries, but i want to generate separately reports date wise, Cash Book Dated:2013-05-01, Cash Book Dated:2013-05-02, Cash Book Dated:2013-05-03 all entries of 1st May generates separately and so on.

Comment: Should we just guess or read your mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i know what your problem is, try to put the date in the group_by sql query, something like this, should do the trick:

```
SELECT vou_date, vou_no, acc_code, acc_name, narration,  ROUND(SUM(receipts),2) AS receipts 
FROM cash_book 
WHERE vou_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND  '2013-05-29' 
AND receipts > 0 
AND vou_no LIKE 'CR' 
GROUP BY vou_date, acc_code
```